# Sending JSON Post HTTP request in java

Tags: java, json, api, http-post

I am trying to connect to an API for getting some information in json format. I need to request the API through json encoded authorization details. Request method is Post. But I am getting error.
I need to get the response in json object. I am using apache HttpClient and apache HttpCore and for Json parsing I am using json-simple-1.1.1. 
Please help me. As I am a novice java developer.

Here is my code

```
public class LonexaApiCon {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String postUrl = "http://myUrl.com/api/get-schedule-data";
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postUrl);

        String access_token= "myaccesstoken";
        String client_id= "myclientId";
        String client_secret= "myClientSecret";
        String username= "myuserName";
        String password= "myPassword";
        String token_type="myTokenType";


        post.setHeader("authorization", (token_type.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + token_type.substring(1))+" "+access_token);
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        json.put("grant_type","password");
        json.put("client_id",client_id);
        json.put("client_secret",client_secret);
        json.put("username",username);
        json.put("password",password);
        json.put("token_type",token_type);
        json.put("access_token",access_token);
        json.put("transport_id","72");

        post.setEntity((HttpEntity) json);
        HttpResponse  response = httpClient.execute(post);

        System.out.println(response.toString());







    }

}
```

getting this following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier.(DefaultHostnameVerifier.java:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:944)
>     at lonexaapicon.LonexaApiCon.main(LonexaApiCon.java:33) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 3 more

Comment: Is`commons-logging.jar` added to your project? Try to add it if not.

Comment: You are missing a dependency to Apache Commons Logging, try to learn to use Maven to build your project, it will simplify dependency management a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the apache HttpCore version to 4.4.3 worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Are u using this dependencies? They work for me.
Except for the code itself, but its another problem

```html
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20171018</version>
            </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I am using jar library files in my project. I am not using maven.

Comment: use then this vesrions